# Вывести все подмножества множества посредством рекурсивной функции С++

Tags: c++, массивы, рекурсия

Ввожу например множество `1 2 3 4`

Должно вывести вроде

```
2 3 4,
1 3 4,
1 2 4,
1 2 3,
1 2,
1 3,
1 4,
2 3,
2 4,
3 4,
1,
2,
3,
4
```

Пока что получается нормально вывести

```
2 3 4,
1 3 4,
1 2 4,
1 2 3
```

Что изменить/дописать, чтоб выводились остальные подмножества?
И мне нужна работа именно с рекурсией

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int rec(int *mas, int n);
int n, m, null;
int main () {
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Array: ";
    m = n;
    null = 0;
    int* mas = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> mas[i];
    }
    rec(mas, n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int rec(int *mas, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i != null) {
            cout << mas[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    null++;
    m--;
    if (m == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else  
        rec(mas, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так устроит?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

vector<int> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

void outMas(const vector<int>&mas, int num, string s)
{
    if (num == mas.size())
    {
        cout << s << '\n';
        return;
    }
    outMas(mas,num+1,s);
    s = s + to_string(mas[num]) + ' ';
    outMas(mas,num+1,s);
}

int main()
{
    outMas(arr,0,"");
}
```

Т.е. каждый вызов работает с элементом `num` - его либо нет, либо он есть. Соответственно вызываем дальше, передавая строку либо без данного элемента, либо с ним...

Comment: Но как это работает?

Comment: Рекурсивно :) Грубо говоря, если мы знаем, как вывести все подмножества из N-1 элементов, то чтобы получить для множества из N элементов, к каждому мы просто можем дописать или ничего (N-й элемент не входит в подмножество), или этот N-й элемент. outMas(mas,num,s) добавляет к строке s поочередно все подмножества из элементов mas, начиная с num. Когда перебраны все элементы (num равно длине mas), выводится соответствующая строка. Так понятнее? P.S. Если ответ устраивает - отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа)...